# How do I pass values from RecyclerView to AnotherActivity with POJO class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pojo

I have a `POJO` class. It holds some Strings and I want to pass values from `RecyclerView` to an `Activity`. I tried something and failed. How do I do that?

> Model

```
public class DetailModel {
    String title;

    public DetailModel() {
    }

    public DetailModel(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

> Adapter, onClick

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                detailModel=new DetailModel();
                detailModels= new ArrayList<>();

                detailModel.setTitle(holder.headerText.getText().toString());

                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);

                context.startActivity(detailIntent);
            }
        });
```

> Another Activity

```
DetailModel detailModel=new DetailModel();

        detailBody.setText(detailModel.getTitle());
```

Comment: What you tried so far, can you show us ? Also if you fail provide logcat or relevant something

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I hav edited the question, check it out pls

Comment: I've posted an answer. Checkout it and decide which way fits you.

Comment: Hacı teşekkür ettim, sagolasin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways to do that, but I will show you simplest one :

In your `onBindViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    final MyView myHolder = (MyView) holder;
    myHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            detailModel.setTitle(holder.headerText.getText().toString());

            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            //To pass your class:
            intent.putExtra("mypojo", details.get(position));
            context.startActivity(detailIntent);

        }
    });

}
```

In this way you must implement `Serializable` in your `POJO` class :

```
public class DetailModel implements Serializable{
String title;

public DetailModel() {
}

public DetailModel(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

And in second `Activity` use this code to get class :

```
getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("mypojo");
//also you can cast extra 
DetailModel detailmodel=(Detailmodel) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("mypojo");
//if you implemented Parcelable
DetailModel detailmodel=(Detailmodel) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("mypojo");
```

This is the first way, in another and faster way is using `Parcelable` , checkout this answer but you must make some effort in `Parcelable` : [how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

I suggest you to use `Parcelable` maybe you need some time to learn it but you can feel speed difference in bigger classes.

Also if you have small amounts of Strings in your POJO, try to use intent extras instead of sending class like that :

```
intent.putExtra("model_name",pojo.getName());
//then get
getIntent().getExtras().getString("model_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

A recycler view by itself doesn't hold any data. That is the job of your adapter. The recyclerview' a job is to display that data and intercept touch events. So on your click listener get a hold of the data(POJO object) and pass that to your activity.